# Can this result be achieved with a recursive cte?

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I currently have a table that looks like this:

```
| A_URN | B_URN | ID |
|-------|-------|----|
| 101   | 901   | 0  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 102   | 901   | 0  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 101   | 902   | 0  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 102   | 902   | 0  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 201   | 902   | 0  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 201   | 903   | 0  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 202   | 903   | 0  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 301   | 904   | 0  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 302   | 904   | 0  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 301   | 905   | 0  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 302   | 905   | 0  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 303   | 905   | 0  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 101   | 906   | 0  |
```

I need to add an identifier that groups all related items together.

For example A_URN 101 is connected to B_URNs 901, 902, and 906 and
B_URNs 901, 902 and 906 also contain A_URNs 102 and 201

A_URN 201 is also connected to B_URN 903 etc. etc.

The end result should look something like:

```
| A_URN | B_URN | ID |
|-------|-------|----|
| 101   | 901   | 1  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 102   | 901   | 1  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 101   | 902   | 1  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 102   | 902   | 1  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 201   | 902   | 1  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 201   | 903   | 1  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 202   | 903   | 1  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 301   | 904   | 2  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 302   | 904   | 2  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 301   | 905   | 2  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 302   | 905   | 2  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 303   | 905   | 2  |
|-------|-------|----|
| 101   | 906   | 1  |
```

I have written a query that accomplishes this using a WHILE() loop, but have been asked to rework it into a recursive CTE.
I have tried, but always end up needing to use a MIN or GROUP BY within the recursive member which is not permitted.

Is it possible to get this kind of result using a recursive query?

Comment: Can you post the solution with the while loop?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use (MSSQL,Oracle)?

Answer (score 0):

If you need MSSQL solution with recursive CTE. Here is a query [from my answer to the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40678381/1554034) adapted to your case:

```
WITH T as 
(
  SELECT A_URN,B_URN, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A_URN) as ID FROM Table14
)
,CTE AS 
(
  SELECT CAST(','+CAST(A_URN AS Varchar(100)) +','+ CAST(B_URN as Varchar(100))+',' as Varchar(MAX)) as GroupCont,
        id
  FROM T
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST(GroupCont+CAST(A_URN AS Varchar(100)) +','+ CAST(B_URN as Varchar(100))+',' AS Varchar(MAX)) as GroupCont,
         pm.id
  FROM CTE 
  JOIN T as pm
  ON 
     (
       CTE.GroupCont LIKE '%,'+CAST(pm.A_URN AS Varchar(100))+',%'
       OR 
       CTE.GroupCont LIKE '%,'+CAST(pm.B_URN AS Varchar(100))+',%'
     )
     AND NOT  
     (
       CTE.GroupCont LIKE '%,'+CAST(pm.A_URN AS Varchar(100))+',%'
       AND 
       CTE.GroupCont LIKE '%,'+CAST(pm.B_URN AS Varchar(100))+',%'
     )
),
T1 AS 
(
 SELECT pm.A_URN,
       pm.B_URN,  
       ISNULL(
        (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM CTE WHERE 
        (
           CTE.GroupCont LIKE '%,'+CAST(pm.A_URN AS Varchar(100))+',%'
           OR 
           CTE.GroupCont LIKE '%,'+CAST(pm.B_URN AS Varchar(100))+',%'
        ))
        ,pm.ID) as ID
FROM T pm
)

SELECT A_URN,B_URN, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS ID 
FROM T1
ORDER BY B_URN,A_URN
```